# ANT SSHEXEC Password Prompt issues with su -c

Tags: shell, ant, ssh, automation, build-automation

I have trying to get round and issue with ANT / SSHEXEC command.

The setup:

Solaris server using NIS and Role based user for runtime activities.

You cannot login directly to the RBAC account, you have to connect as personal user and the su to the user - I have been advised that SUDO is not an option in this environment.

So so scenario is I am building some ANT scripts to build, deploy and then run a set of scripts on a remote server.

The build and deploy is fine as this is being carried out as my user, but when try to connect using SSHEXEC to su -c $user I have an issue, where the shell responds with a password prompt, but I cannot enter anything.

So here I either want a solution that lets me type the password in and continue or a way to pass the password to the prompt as a variable I have entered.

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
<target name="install-products">
  <sshexec host="${remote.host1}" 
    username="${remote.user}" 
    password="${remote.pwd}"
    command="/usr/bin/su - $user -c cd ${remote.install.dir}/OracleSunJDK;./installJAVA.sh -p project -e 935"
    usepty="true"
    trust="true"
    failonerror="true"/>
</target>
```

So I am connecting in as my user, example ssh -t cambolie@${remote.host1}... which the user and password is passed as above, its the su -c that then causes the prompt to appear.

This is what currently happens:

```
install-products:
[sshexec] Connecting to ${remote.host1}:22
[sshexec] cmd : /usr/bin/su - ${su-user}  -c cd /var/tmp/weblogic/RP_WEBLOGIC_J2EE_1.0.0.0/install/OracleSunJDK;./installJAVA.sh -p project -e 935
[sshexec] Password:
```

It just hangs at this stage.

Can anyone help?

Comment: search here for ssh keyless connections. It will require some work and access to your remote machines. Good luck.

Comment: Unfortunately not an option as I cannot connect directly to the runtime user over SSH, thus the need to su - ${su-user} -c.

Comment: Seeing the same issue on ant 1.8.4.  This is not a connection problem, it can initiate the ssh session with a private key file or user/pass just fine.  But the "usepty" for input into su, sudo etc just seems to hang

Comment: What are you versions of ant, java, jsch ? You may try to use the latest version 0.1.50 of Jsch => http://sourcefore.net/projects/jsch/files/jsch.jar and set the verbose attribute of sshexec task='true' (default='false') to get more output.

Comment: typo, get JSch 0.1.50 here => http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsch/files/jsch.jar

Answer (score 0):

The following is one of the possible solutions.

1. Setup key-based  `scp` from your host machine to your target machine.
2. Modify your build script to `scp` a marker file (i.e. `begin.install` , zero byte file)
3. Setup a cron on the target machine to look for the marker file, and once found, start the set of steps to be performed on that server. Once done, delete the marker file.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
   <property name="password" value="MYPASS"/>

    <!-- Keep the closing property tag on the new line as su needs the CR/LF-->
    <property name="password.crlf">${password}<!-- do not remove the CR/LF-->
    </property>
    <!-- Keep the closing property tag on the new line as su needs the CR/LF-->

  <sshexec host="${server}"
                 username="${username1}"
                 password="${password1}"
                 trust="yes"
                 verbose="yes"
                 usepty="true"
                 inputproperty="password.crlf"
                 command="su - otheruser -c ls"
        />
```